# Check if the dictionary contains a certain word

Tags: java, dictionary

I've come up with the following problem: suppose the words are being added into the dictionary that is based on some data strucure. For example, the following words are added:

```
"bob", "dad", "bad"
```

And suppose I want to check if a certain word is in the dictionary by implementing the method:

```
public boolean checkWord(String word)
```

However, the character `'.'` also represents some letter so if, for example:

```
checkWord(".ob")
```

then the result is `true` (as '.' can be substituted or represented by `b` and would be `bob`). Or another example is:

```
checkWord("..d")
```

which also return `true` (because of `"dad"`).

I need help only with how to check if the words match. Suppose the data structure is `ArrayList` and dictionary is represented as `myList`. My code is giving always `true` for whatever `String` I pass. Please could smb please help me out? I just want to know how to return true if a dictionary contains `"bob"` and a passing check word is `".ob"`, then how can I omit the character `'.'` and check other characters? Thanks in advance!

```
public boolean checkWord(String word){
   boolean result = false;
   if(myList.contains(word)){
       return true; 
   }
   else{
       for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){
          if(myList.get(i).length() == word.length()){
             for(int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++){
                 if(word.charAt(j) == myList.get(i).charAt(j)){
                    result = true;
                 }
             }
          }
       }
   }
return result;
}
```

Comment: `b.b` will that yield `true` as well because of `bob`? Meaning does `.` act as a wildcard?

Comment: Could you at least try and write a good title for your question.

Comment: @Emz, yes, you're right

Comment: @bhspencer, does it work well now?

Comment: Have a loop go through each character in the dicitonary word and passed in word and compare if each character is equal.  If they are, keep going, if not break the loop and return false.  If the character in the passed in word is a ".", continue thorugh the loop.  If you reach the end without breaking, return true.

Comment: Yep, I'm afraid that this problem requires actually writing software, as odious a task as that may seem.  (Though you could finesse it using a database with wildcard search capabilities.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to use regex.

```
public boolean checkWord(String word){
    boolean result = false;
    if(myList.contains(word)){
      return true; 
    }
    else{
        word += "$";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(word);
        for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){
            Matcher m = p.matcher(myList.get(i));
            if(m.find()){
                result = true;
                break;
            }else{
                result = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```